# Justified multi-value field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of data that contains 10 point values based on a score for an event (0 - 9 points). If a time is within the range, the point is awarded. There are 20 possible events. Is this a valid use of a multi-value field?

example:

```
Event 1A times 18.50, 19.11, 19.77, 20.03
Event 2C times 58.50, 60.91, 62.55, 63.99
```

If the event is 1A and the time is 19.66, this fall into the 2nd and 3rd position - the score is then 2

If the event is 2C and the time is 63.77, this fall into the 3rd and 4th position - the score is then 3

Regards

More Detail:

```
Key|Event|Type|PointTable (seconds)
1|200E|R|93.86, 94.06, 94.25, 94.45, 94.65, 94.85, 95.05, 95.25, 95.45, 95.65
2|200A|I|98.26, 98.44, 98.63, 98.81, 98.99, 99.18, 99.37, 99.55, 99.74, 99.94
3|200E|I|110.74, 110.94, 111.15, 111.35, 111.56, 111.76, 111.97, 112.18, 112.38, 112.59
```

Key = unique key, Event is the EventCode, Type is not important, PointTable is the list of seconds....

I have another table that contains RESULTS which includes an EventCode and a TIME. To produce a query, I want a score identified for that TIME. So I use the EventCode to find the corresponding list of times... and where the TIME fits in the array of times produces a 'SCORE'

The time for 200E (1 key) would be in a record for a results of an athletic activity and there needs to be a determination what that time's relative score would be 0=93.86 or less, 1=94.06 or less, 2=94.25 or less... etc. So taking a time from an event 200E with a time of 94.01 would fall into "1=94.06 or less" and therefore the score given to the event with a time of 94.01 would be given "1" ... each event has 10 'scores' and the point value represents the position in the list of scores. Does this help?

-lookup is used to determine the position in the list of values to determine the score...

Comment: Showing the table definition and some sample data along with clear rules on choosing position, would be helpful.

Comment: This is a clear violation of 1st Normal Form, so my answer will be: NO

Comment: How then do you suggest the data be handled?

It is only used to determine a 'score' ...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by the following:

```
 k | code | t | lower     | upper     | score  
---+------+---+-----------+-----------+-------
 1 | 200E | R |  0.000000 | 93.860000 | 600  
 2 | 200E | R | 93.860000 | 94.060000 | 597  
 3 | 200E | R | 94.060000 | 94.250000 | 594
```

So 1NF is now intact!